# move data from one table to another and set the id from the other table in the first

Tags: mysql, move

I'll try to keep it simple.

Got two tables, tblSource and tblDestination
I want to move part of the columns in tblSource to tblDestination
AND set the correct FK value in tblSource column media_id (FK to tblDestination).

(REASON: there will be more sourcetables linking to tblDestination).

I found the way to move the data:

```
INSERT INTO tblDestination 
SELECT null, extra_fields 
FROM tblSource;
```

But from this I can't get the ID of the new rows in tblDestination to update tblSource

Comment: does tblSource have a unique ID?

Comment: @ilion they both have